# Looping Horizontal Data and Creating Multiple Records per Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I have a stored procedure called dbo.SalesmanAccts that returns the following data:

[image]

I want to update a header and a detail table, namely SalesmanHeader and SalesmanDetail, with the results of dbo.SalesmanAccts.
I want to INSERT INTO SalesmanHeader (SalesmanID, SalesmanName, SalesmanAddress) which is no problem.

The tricky part is the following.
I want to insert MULTIPLE records per salesman in the SalesmanDetail table for each account. That is it say, I want to have the SalesmanDetail table to look like the following:

[image]

Notice that account1, account 2, and account3 are all stored as separate records in the SalesmanDetail table.

Is there a way to loop the results of dbo.SalesmanAccts and have it do both INSERT INTO statements in one new stored procedure without creating a separate one for inserting the header records and another one for inserting the detail records?
Is this even possible?

I am working on SQL server 2008R2

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you insert rows into SalesmanHeader table ?

Comment: you want to unpivot the data. (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mab/archive/2008/06/16/sql-server-2005-unpivot-command-changings-columns-to-rows-normalizing.aspx) OR http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx  The concept here is to `insert into table name () values (Select unpivot data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT SalesmanDetail
      (SalesmanID, SalesmanName, Account)
SELECT SalesmanID, SalesmanName, Account
FROM dbo.SalesmanAccts
UNPIVOT (Account FOR AccountNumber IN (Account1,Account2,Account3) ) p
```

Comment: UNPIVOT did exactly what i was looking for - thanks for the help!